# Confluent Hypergeometric Function behaviour when $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'm very new to confluent hypergeometric functions so please bear with me. 
What I'm trying to prove is that $$M \left (\frac{c+m}{2m}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{m}{2d}x^2  \right ) \rightarrow \infty \quad (1)$$ and $$U \left (\frac{c+m}{2m}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{m}{2d}x^2  \right ) \rightarrow 0 \quad (2)$$ when  $x \rightarrow \infty$. I know that's the case because I can compute their values, but I don't know how to show it.

I know from Abramowitz and Stegun's pocketbook that $M(a, b, z) = \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)}e^z z^{a-b}[1+O(|z|^{-1})] $ when $|z| \rightarrow \infty$. $(1)$ is pretty clear from this because $a$ and $b$ are fixed. What about $(2)$?

Comment: Hint: Use Abramowitz/Stegun 13.1.8 or http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E6
$$ U(a,b,z) = z^{-a} (1+O(|z|^{-1})\;\; \text{as}\;\;\Re z \rightarrow \infty.$$